# change default Jupyter output for R kernel to look like print()?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, repr

I do a lot of teaching for Python in Jupyter Notebooks and am trying to get my colleagues to teach R using Jupyter. (Note: I am Python guy, not an R user).

One of my colleagues is very bothered by Jupyter's default output format for a simple R vector (which is think comes from display() or a repr-like function) and difference with output from explicit print(). He wants to see print()-like output all the time, without having to explicitly type print(). He thinks Jupyter is inadequate as a teaching tool as a result. See the example:

[image: display vs print default behavior]

Is there a way to change the default output in Jupyter when working with R, so the default display behavior looks like print()?

Sorry if this the wrong place to post, I couldn't find any other online forum that seemed knowledgable.

I have been searching for jupyter config options, but haven't found anything useful.  I also tried the https://github.com/IRkernel IRKernel github site - I think this code controls how R objects are displayed.  Any ideas for what else I might try?

Comment: Try `IRkernel` plus `IRdisplay` https://github.com/IRkernel/IRdisplay